# Taylor series about 0 for $\frac{x^{2}}{e^{2x}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion

I got the following question:

The Taylor series about 0 for $e^{x}$ is:
$
e^{x} = 1 +x + \dfrac{1}{2!}x^{2} + \dfrac{1}{3!}x^3 + \dfrac{1}{4!} x^4 + \dots \qquad \text{for $x \in \mathbb{R}$}
$

And then I'm asked to find the coefficient of $x^{5}$ in the Taylor series about 0 for $\dfrac{x^{2}}{e^{2x}}$

What I learned, before this question, was to find Taylor series from existing Taylor series, so for example I would be able to calculate the Taylor series about 0 for $e^{2x}$ by simply substituting $x$ with $2x$, but I'm lost at this question.

I'm also able to find other Taylor series by differentiating and integratng existing ones.

How do I approach the question with my existing knowledge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+....$$

plug $-2x$ into this expansion
$$e^{-2x}=1+(-2x)+\frac{(-2x)^2}{2!}+\frac{(-2x)^3}{3!}+....$$

hence
$$\frac{x^2}{e^{2x}}=x^2*e^{-2x}=x^2(1+(-2x)+\frac{(-2x)^2}{2!}+\frac{(-2x)^3}{3!}+....)$$

Comment: "let x=−2x" Hmmm...

Comment: @Did  Exactly, we all understand it, and I had the exact same thought, what's the best way to put it ?  ... like sub -2x for x ?

Comment: @Shailesh Yes, or "plug -2x into this expansion" or "use this for -2x" or...

Comment: #Did. I like the word plug - I will use that myself when the need arises. Thanks.

Comment: @Did thanks for your comment

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Outline :

You already know the Taylor series for $e^x$.
Now, write $\frac {x^2}{e^{2x}}$ as $x^2e^{-2x}$ as expand $e^{-2x}$ using the Taylor series. All you need is coefficient of $x^3$ in that to get your required coefficient. Can you do all these substitutions ? The answer should be $\frac{-4}{3}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\frac{x^2}{e^{2x}}=x^2 e^{-2x}$.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2/e^{2x}$=$x^2e^{-2x}$=$x^2[1-2x+(-2x)^2/2! +(-2x)^3/3!+....\infty]$,Multiply $x^2$ inside and you get your result.
Coefficient of $x^5 =-4/3$